# Javascript blunder

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a webpage that will allow my employees to enter a number and get a number that has run through an equation.  I want it to do two simple math problems as follows and output the number that's larger.

**Equations**

> x+150=y
>
> x*1.5+89=z

Then display the larger variable.
I can't get it to work.
I'm pretty sure it's a major noob mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateOutput() { 
        //get form
    var form = document.getElementById("calc");
        //get output
    var out = form.elements["z"];
        //get two numbers
    var num1 = parseInt(form.elements["x"].value);
        //add 150
    var num2 = 150;
        //multiply 1.5;
    var num3 = 1.5;
        //add 89
    var num4 = 89;
        //amount1
    var amount1;
        //amount2
    var amount2;
        //set output depending on amount

        //add
        amount1.value = num1+num2;
        //multiple
        amount2.value = num1*num3+num4;

    If amount1 > amount2 Then
        out.value = amount1.value
    Else
        out.value = amount2.value
}

</script>
```

Comment: Problem should be the `if then else part`, try `if (xx) {...} else {....}`

Comment: @fuyushimoya   `If (amount1 > amount2) {
 amount1.value = out.value;
} Else {amount2.value = out.value;
}`

Comment: Why uppercase? just `if` and `else`

Comment: Get your languages straight. Watch for syntax errors in the console.

Comment: This question took me back to the days when VBScript worked in browser (IE).

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive title. If you can't describe the problem, other than "blunder" then do more analysis before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors:

1. `amount1.value` only works if you define `amount` as `Object`, and it doesn't need to be object here. Same for amount2.
2. `if else` notation error

Better go to some tutorial sites like [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) or [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript) or buy some books.

Changes of your code, with added form, input to demonstrate.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calc">
    <input type="number" name="x"/>
    <input type="number" name="z"/>
</form>
    <button onclick="updateOutput();">click</button>
<script>
    function updateOutput() { 
        //get form
    var form = document.getElementById("calc");
        //get output
    var out = form.elements["z"];
        //get two numbers
    var num1 = parseInt(form.elements["x"].value);
        //add 150
    var num2 = 150;
        //multiply 1.5;
    var num3 = 1.5;
        //add 89
    var num4 = 89;
        //amount1
    var amount1;
        //amount2
    var amount2;
        //set output depending on amount
      
        //add
        // It's ok to just assign value to them.
        amount1 = num1+num2;
        //multiple
        amount2 = num1*num3+num4;
     
     // Also here, don't use amountX.value.
    if (amount1 > amount2) {
        out.value = amount1
    } else {
        out.value = amount2
    }
}
</script>
```